# How does one simulate continuous gravity using a discrete timestep?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, physics

While gravity in real life is continuous, computers are limited to discrete calculations.

Therefore, a seemingly correct projectile simulation inevitably drifts off.

For example:

```
// Repeat once per frame
position += velocity * deltaTime;
velocity += gravity * deltaTime;
```

Graphed, compared to the actual projectile formula
[image: Two datasets merged. While they look equal at first, the discrete data drifts off over time.]

Comment: Ballistic projectile motion can be solved exactly, as described below. But if you are interested in techniques for numerically solving more general systems of differential equations, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of [Euler's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method)

Using differentiation, you can find a better formula. Since discrete calculations only "drift" if they are non-linear, you only need to alter the position/time calculation.

```
// Repeat once per frame
position += velocity * deltaTime + gravity * Math.pow(deltaTime, 2.0) / 2.0;
velocity += gravity * deltaTime;
```

Even large timesteps align perfectly with the continuous graph:

[image: Improved code, merged with a continuous graph. The points are directly on the line]

Comment: what happens if you compute the velocity with gravity first and then update the position?